# How long will it take for errors that were fixed to be cleared from Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, 404

If you see the image below, it shows a number of errors, but it doesn't show the URL lists. I tried to download the list of errors via the CSV format, but it still doesn't show the list of URLs, and it only shows 5 errors.

[image]

How long will it take for Google to clear the large number of errors? The `404` issues were already resolved on the website's end.

Only problem here was the number of errors being reported in Google Search Console that we want to clear. Does it take a lot of time before it will clear them?

Comment: Google Search Console is notoriously slow. It will take quite a bit of time.

Comment: That is a lot of 404 errors, good work dealing with them.   They shouldn't cause your website any problems now that you have fixed them, even if it does take Google a while to clear them from that report.